# Variable turned out to have "Inf" and "NA's" from math function

Tags: r

Why variable "rate" turned out to have "Inf" and "NA's" from simple math function?`rate=(outcome/pop19)*100000

I did the exact same calculation for "rate" on its parent data with no problem. "Compplot" is simply a subset of fewer variables.

[image: My data summary]

Comment: You have values of 0 for pop19, which cause trouble for your division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both pop19 and outcome have 0s.

```
> 1/0
[1] Inf
> 0/0
[1] NaN
> summary(c(1/0, 0/0))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
    Inf     Inf     Inf     Inf     Inf     Inf       1 
> summary(c(1, 1/0, 0/0))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      1     Inf     Inf     Inf     Inf     Inf       1
```

When dividing a positive non-zero value by 0 we get Inf which is where Inf is coming in your rate calculation.  If you divide 0/0 you get NaN and summary reports NaN values as NA which is where those are probably coming from.

Without access to your actual data we have to assume that this is what is causing your issues.

Comment: wow, of course it's a dumb question but what i was puzzled was that its parent data had not turned in "inf" and "NA's" in the presence of zero values in pop19 and outcome. more importantly, have i now realized that my GEE model using SAS must had simply ignored zero values. Lots of inspection work is getting started with this observation. I had totally overlooked this issue in my data. How oblivious but good it's captured. Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, that 2790 of "inf" and "NA's" were ignored in my regression analysis. Thanks again.